# Simple sign up validation form by scanner Java

Tags: java

I am new to Learning java so i am stuck and i don't understand how to fix this error i am stuck here for last 2 days i am making a a validation sign up form kindly explain me what i have to do to fix this error and need more suggestion or any other way to develop a form like this is university assignment.
Form development with scanner using nextint, nextLine etc and sorry for the bad english i tried my best to explain the problem i mention error below at the end of the code kindly check it .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vali{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter User Name :");
        String uname = s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Password :");
        String pass = s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Number :");
        if (s.hasNextInt()) {
            int numberr = s.nextInt() ; 
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please Enter The Number");
        }

        if (!uname.equals("") && !pass.equals("") && !numberr.equals("") ) {
             System.out.println("logged in");
        } else if(!uname.equals("")  && !numbe.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("fill the feild");
        } else {
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }
    }   
}
```

I am getting this error kindly guide me

```
Vali.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    if (!uname.equals("") && !pass.equals("") && !numberr.equals("") ){
                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable numberr
  location: class Vali
```

Comment: `numberr` is within the scope of an `if` and cannot be accessed outside it. Try defining it as a global variable

Answer (score 0):

The variable `numberr` was created in another if statement before you used it, therefore it can't be found if it wasn't set. Also `numberr` can never equal `""` since it's an Integer and not a String. To make your code work write it like this:

```
int numberr = 0;
if (s.hasNextInt()) {
    numberr = s.nextInt() ; 
} else {
    System.out.println("Please Enter The Number");
}
if (!uname.equals("") && !pass.equals("") && numberr != 0 ){
    System.out.println("logged in");
}
```

An even better way to do this, is not to check if `numberr` has the standard value 0, since the user might want to set it to 0. So you could introduce a boolean value to determine if `numberr` was set. The code would then look like this:

```
boolean b = false;
int numberr = 0;
if (s.hasNextInt()) {
    numberr = s.nextInt() ; 
    b = true;
} else {
    System.out.println("Please Enter The Number");
}
if (!uname.equals("") && !pass.equals("") && b ){
    System.out.println("logged in");
}
```

I don't know what you are trying to achieve exactly, but if you want to force the user to put a number in, you might want to consider using loops as well like this, then you won't have to check if `numberr` is set, since the user is forced to set it:

```
while(!s.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Please Enter The Number");
}
int numberr = s.nextInt() ; 
if (!uname.equals("") && !pass.equals("")){
    System.out.println("logged in");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change as below :

1 - declare number out of the if

2 - use == to compare int instead equal method in the if condition

```
 public class Vali{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int numberr = 0;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter User Name :");
        String uname = s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Password :");
        String pass = s.nextLine();


        System.out.println("Enter Number :");

if (s.hasNextInt()) {
        numberr = s.nextInt() ; 
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Number");
}
    if (!uname.equals("") && !pass.equals("") && !(numberr == {SOME_NUMBER}) ){
        System.out.println("logged in");
    }
        else if(!uname.equals("")  && !numbe.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("fill the feild");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("invalid");
        }
    }   
    }
```